# CBCentral connection to a CBPeripheral without a scan

Tags: ios, ios7, core-bluetooth

I have two iOS devices on 7.1, one functioning as a CBCentral and one as a CBPeripheral. Both devices are running software of my own creation, so all UUIDs/CBService/CBCharacteristic are generated by me, and all parameters are fixed and known at all times.

As well, both devices have access to a shared server for storing any arbitrary data I may desire.

Given that I am in control of the entire ecosystem, is there a way to have a CBCentral device connect to the CBPeripheral device without having to first do a `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:` call? In a sense, I want to "teach" the Central about the existence of the Peripheral before the two devices come into contact with one another.

Perhaps there is there some data or value the CBPeripheralManager unit could post to the server that the CBCentralManager unit could pull, then directly alloc/init its own CBPeripheral object for use with `connectPeripheral:options:`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. Core Bluetooth uses internally generated UUIDs to identify the peers. If you don't scan, the system will not identify the peripherals and you will not be able to invoke the `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` method to obtain a CBPeripheral that you can call the `connectPeripheral:` on.

Since there is no way to inject the UUIDs, you must scan at least once. But depending on many factors, probably many times.

Comment: I would also add that you can't store the `CBPeripheral` as it doesn't implements `NSCoding` protocol. That's what I wanted to do at first, in my app (user get a scan at first launch, and never after). You will have to scan at every launch.

Comment: @allpro - Well, that confirms my own findings. That "internally generated UUID" is the big blocker on this one, it seems. I was hoping someone smarter than me had a way!

Comment: @Jissay - Yes, I have found that as well. Honestly, the need to scan doesn't frustrate me as much as the fact that two devices in background mode can't discover each other, despite the fact that they are broadcasting and scanning specifically for each other and no one else. Lack of a service advertisement + inability to scan generically for all nearby devices while in background is a real one-two punch in the nether regions.

Comment: Sure, this inability has screwed up many projects already. Also, the Apple argument that this would be a privacy issue doesn't seem to be very relevant. Maybe the power requirement is the only plausible reason for it. Anyway, we have to live with it until someone comes up with a battery that lasts an order of magnitude longer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the privacy concern if it is opt-in by the involved parties. I do see the power concern; however, devices like the Estimote have two years of life on a single lithium battery. I would think an iOS device could manage a day's worth of broadcast with each nightly charge of the unit. Well, here's hoping for the future!

Comment: I don't get this. I'm using an abstraction layer (from the Bluetooth Chip Manufacturer) which exactly does that: stores the UDID and gets them back with `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:`. Even _worst_, the very first time (after the scan), I'm keeping a pointer to that `CBPeripheral` but still calling `connectPeripheral` doesn`t do anything if it wasn't done after a `scan`...